# xrdp session's resolution corrupted

Tags: xubuntu, display-resolution, remote-desktop

I have Xubuntu installed 22.04 on a machine. I connect to it via xrdp from a Windows 10 laptop.

I connect with "mstsc".

Remote access works, but there is an annoying issue, a few times in a week the remote screen resolution (?) is unexpectedly corrupted.

What I experience is that unexpectedly everything became bigger (as if screen resolution was changed) and I have to scroll/pan the remote screen in the mstsc window.

If I close the session, change resolution in mstsc's settings then connect again, then everything is OK, UNTIL I move the mouse.

Here is a screenshot taken when the problem arised, after reconnecting to the remote host but before mouse movement:

[image: screenshot before mouse movement]

Here is a screenshot after mouse movement:

[image]

I this state, I can't enlarge the mstsc window to accomodate the whole remote screen, I can only pan it.

Right now I can only solve the problem with restarting the Xubuntu machine.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that xfce has a feature that zooms the screen. It can be activated with alt + mouse scrolling.

Probably I am accidentally zooming the screen a few times a week while "alt+tabbing" and handling the mouse simultenously.

Now that I learned this feature I can reset the screen with alt + scroll, or can switch it off altogether in "settings editor / xfwm4 / zoom desktop".